# Elements of monoids are equal if relatively prime powers of the elements are equal

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers, monoid

Assume that $a$ is left cancelable monoid. That is $ab=ac$ implies $b=c$

Prove that if $a^m=b^m$ and $a^n=b^n$ such that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then $a=b$.

Here is what I've done so far $a^m=b^m\implies a^na^m=a^nb^m \implies a^na^m=b^nb^m\implies a^{n+m}=b^{n+m}$.

I figure that this is where the fact that $\gcd(m,n)=1$ comes into play and shows that $a=b$, but I am not sure why. Have I gone in the wrong direction?

Comment: Is $m+n-1$ a multiple of $m$ or $n$ if $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) ensures that $1=xm+yn$ for some integers $x,y$ if $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Comment: There are no negative exponents in a general monoid, however.

Comment: Well, yes. If $x<0$, say, then write it as $1-xm=yn$, then both are positive, then use these as exponents for $a$ and $b$.